# MS Project file open in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ms-project

I have uploaded MS Project files in my SP Foundation librarty. But when I wan't to open it in browser I get an error:

no apps are installed to open this type of link (ms-project).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer from Juan Pablo Pussacq Laborde >

There is no application to open project in the browser. What exists is Microsoft Project Server, but does not work on SharePoint Foundation. You need to install SharePoint Enterprise and Project Server . It also requires Microsoft Project Professional as a client

See https://products.office.com/en/project/enterprise-project-server

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177256/ms-project-file-open-in-sharepoint